# Start 3Ds Max from C# .NET application and then send commands to it

Tags: c#, .net, autodesk, 3dsmax, maxscript

I am trying to start 3Ds max from a C# .NET application and send commands to it.
I can start it as a process and send a starting command but then I don't have full control over sending commands and receiving outputs.

I am intermediate level in MAXScript and beginner in C#

Last thing I tried was with this code:

```
using Autodesk.Max;

IGlobal global = GlobalInterface.Instance;
IInterface14 coreInterface = global.COREInterface14;
```

But it also won't start max.

I assume that correct way is to Autodesk.Max and start from there, but I just can't find right documentation for that, searched in SDK too.